# Error handler called with status 200

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code. When I do request the error callback function is called and yet the status of the request os **200 - OK**

```
    return $.ajax({
        url : url,
        contentType : 'application/json',
        dataType : "json",
        type : 'GET',
        async : async,
        success : function(data) {
            onSuccess(data);
        },
        error : function(error) {

            if(error.status === 401){
                if(window.location.pathname.indexOf("login.html") < 0){
                    window.location = "/login.html";
                }
            }


            if (onFailure) {
                onFailure(error);
            }
        }

    });
```

Whenever I do the request the error callback handler is called upon response:

```js
        onFailure = function(xhr, ajOp, err) {
            console.log(xhr.status);
            console.log(err);
        }
```

And in the console I get:

> 200
>
> undefined

How come with status code `200` and `undefined` error I get the error callback called?

Comment: My initial guess would be because the server is handling the request and responding back successfully but the data returned is not `JSON` as you've indicated that you wanted in the `dataType` parameter.

Comment: Check the network tab of the console to ensure the request is actually being sent and what the response is. This behaviour can happen when the response cannot be deserialised to the format you selected - in your case, JSON

Comment: @War10ck Re: `async`, I thought the same initially but OP is using an `async` variable - presumably a boolean, hopefully set to `true`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Ah, good catch. I missed that altogether. Edited my above comment...

Comment: Yes it was due to the wrong format. When sent JSON from the backend, the `success` handler is executed. Thank you all